# How do I send MouseWheelUp and ignore modifiers being held?

Tags: autohotkey

I'm trying to add some behavior that I have bound to shift+MouseWheelUp but occasionally the shift modifier is being applied to what I am sending, here is a simple repro case with output:

```
#NoEnv  ; Recommended for performance and compatibility with future AutoHotkey releases.
; #Warn  ; Enable warnings to assist with detecting common errors.
SendMode Input  ; Recommended for new scripts due to its superior speed and reliability.
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%  ; Ensures a consistent starting directory.

#InstallKeybdHook
#UseHook On
#MaxHotkeysPerInterval 200


+WheelUp::
    send {a}
return
```

This will output:

```
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaAaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaAaaaaaaaaaaaaaaAaaaaaaaaaaaaa
```

The script I am writing is supposed to let me use ctrl+mousewheel to mimic standard mousewheel behavior, but sometimes it will still send ctrl+mousewheel causing things to zoom in and out.

## UseHook is something I found suggested for similar problems but had no impact.

Thank you

Comment: I was able to reduplicate similar behavior--it appears to be a bug with AutoHotkey (or possibly a lower-level issue that AutoHotkey does not alleviate)

Comment: Thank you so much for verifying @JJohnston2 I have just learned to live with it, but when I went down the rabbit hole no one seemed to think it was possible.